# A way to insert gettext calls automatically?

Tags: php, internationalization, gettext

I'm using gettext in PHP to internationalise some code, so I'm going through it and changing code like this:

```
<h1>Hello world</h1>
```

to this:

```
<h1><?php echo gettext('Hello world'); ?></h1>
```

However, the code I've inherited is quite large and has lots of strings that need translating - so I was wondering if there was a way to do this automatically?

Comment: what language are source files in? PHP mixed into HTML or pure HTML?

Comment: You can just use `_()` instead of `gettext()`, to reduce your work bit. But sadly I don't think so there way to get it called automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would be extremely difficult.  Here are some potential approaches and their problems.

**Approach 1: Parsing PHP Files**

1. use [`token_get_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) to parse a PHP source file.
2. Look for all of the `T_INLINE_HTML` tokens, which represent the portions of the file that are not PHP code.
3. Find and replace text in those portions of the file.

*Problem: the only way to reliably find text to replace is by [parsing the HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/1919238).  But the non-PHP portions of the file are not parsable on their own.  They are fragmented and depend on inline PHP code to generate a complete, parse-able file.*

**Approach 2: Parsing the Output HTML Files**

1. Save your site's output HTML files from your browser.  This will give you complete HTML files to parse.
2. [Parse those HTML files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/1919238), saving the text strings that need replacing.
3. Go back to the original PHP files, search for those text strings and replace them.

*Problem: you are once again faced with the problem of not being able to parse the PHP file.  A simple regex approach would work better in this case, because you are searching for exact strings, but it still would not be 100% reliable.  And you would not be able to tell what part of the HTML source was from HTML, and what part was generated by PHP.*

I think you will be best off doing this by hand.  Make yourself a good keyboard macro in your editor, so that once you select text, you can convert it to the PHP function with one keystroke.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks. I think I agree with you - doing it by hand is the most reliable way for now. I wouldn't want a parser to replace some text unless I was sure about it. Having a macro to wrap selected text is an excellent idea, hadn't occurred to me. One vim macro coming up! :-)

Answer (score 3):

**Approach 3: parse the source php files as HTML with processing instructions, or "what php documents really are"**

this won't be perfect, but it is a starting point:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

// load source
$dom->loadHTML('
  <html>
   <body>
    <h1>I\'m a title</h1>
    <p>My name is <?php echo $myname; ?></p>
    <style>
       p { margin-bottom: 1em; }
    </style>
    <script>
       alert(\'a really funny script that we don\\\'t want to enclose\');
    </script>
   </body>
  </html>');


//get all text nodes
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$textnodes = $xpath->evaluate('/html/body//*[not(self::script)][not(self::style)]/text()');

//store a list of translation keys:
$keys = array();

//wrap text nodes into php processing instructions
foreach($textnodes as $node) {
  $content = $node->nodeValue;
  $keys[] = $content;
  $content = trim(addcslashes($content, '\\\''));
  $wrap = $dom->createProcessingInstruction('php', 'gettext(\'' . $content . '\'); ?');
  $node->parentNode->replaceChild($wrap, $node);
}

//output or save the result;
echo $dom->saveHTML();

//output or store the keys, a little help for creating the translation files
print_r($keys);
```

test it here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/559542d98e8ddc60eeb7e156888d9d2fda61b843

the snippet above outputs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
        <h1><?php gettext('I\'m a title'); ?></h1>
        <p><?php gettext('My name is'); ?><?php echo $myname; ?></p>
        <style>
           p { margin-bottom: 1em; }
        </style><script>
           alert('a really funny script that we don\'t want to enclose');
        </script></body></html>
Array
(
    [0] => I'm a title
    [1] => My name is 
)
```

Comment: Nice solution, like it. I think I'd want to add some sort of confirmation to each one though, kind of like search and replace in a text editor that asks you to confirm a replace or move onto the next one. I'm going to go with doing it manually for the moment, but if I get time later I'll look into adding that to your code. Thanks!